# How do I get the browser to zoom in / out using html code?

Tags: browser, zooming

I'm new to code and need to get the browser to zoom in and out, but can't get any of the codes people have listed in other questions to work! I'm entering the code into a html code editor widget. The code I have seen that's supposed to work is as follows:

```
  #iframe{
     zoom: 0.75;
     -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
     -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
     -o-transform: scale(0.75);
     -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
     -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
     -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0; }
```

How do I get this to work in html please can I have the full code if possible.